# How do I stop a 'signature mismatch' error from a module file under DerivedData in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, mismatch, deriveddata

We have an iOS project that, when built with XCode 12.5, will error with something similar the following:

> Module file '/Users/revolt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/J3JDK8UPXZ4K/Foundation-39SXNSRMYWPGZ.pcm' is out of date and needs to be rebuilt: signature mismatch

This does not happen on the first build, but after the cache has been generated and can be 'solved' by deleting the DerivedData folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in XCode](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9071199). It doesn't appear to happen in the XCode 13 beta, at the time of writing. Workaround is to "...disable the global module index by adding -fno-modules-global-index to OTHER_CFLAGS.".

Comment: Hi, I am using XCode 13.2 and still reproduce this bug. Also setting -fno-modules-global-index to OTHER_CFLAGS do not resolve it. Did you manage to fix it just by upgrading XCode?

Comment: Yes, but I probably cleared out the DerivedData too. I no longer see this issue on XCode 13.1. Not tried 13.2 yet.

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 14.2, particularly when using Firebase. Damn annoying.